# Issue with docker image websphere9, console not work when expose others ports

Tags: dockerfile, websphere

I'm build the docker image from 135353539817.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/websphere:9.0.0.11, and the console only works when I expose the default ports 9080/9043, when a try mapping the default 9043 to 9143 for example by compose or docker run, its not works.

I'm tried change the serverindex.xml and virtualhosts.xml, but din't  works too!

Someone had this issue or something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of WebSphere. The admin console port will have to be exposed on 9043 only. In general, you shouldn't be using the admin console very much when using WebSphere in a container, because none of the settings you change will be saved if the container needs to restart for some reason since the original image the container was created from remains unchanged.

Have a look at the recommended [best practices](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional#best-practices) for using the WebSphere image. This will help you use it in a way that works more smoothly for containers.